# Why The OpenGL ES texture object will be deleted as a result of call to SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am referring [SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#detachFromGLContext()), it mentioned, "The OpenGL ES texture object will be deleted as a result of this call."

Anyone please explain why framework need to delete this texture object when calling detach, Because the texture is created outside SurfaceTexture and provided to constructor. So, I expect to use the texture even after detach and creator should be able to control its life cycle.

We are trying to use this with combination of attach method and MediaCodec. In our use case, we need to copy the video frame texture for the future use.

Following is the sample code to create SurfaceTexture:

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
```

Then a surface will be created and pass to MediaCodec as following code sample

```
Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
MediaCodec videoDecoder.configure(..., surface, null, 0);
```

While performing the decoding, once a video frame decoded in to texture, I am trying keep the texture and assign different texture to the SurfaceTexture, so that I can use that later and decoder can decode another frame to the new texture.

```
surfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext();
surfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(newTexture);
```

But the issue is android framework delete the texture. My point is it should be a bug or there should be a reason to delete the texture.

Answer (score 0):

Each openGL item is bound to a context so as it is detached it must also be deleted.

The context is responsible for creating buffers and handling states which are bound with some id or enumeration (same thing but enumeration is predefined). So when the context is deleted all its items are deleted as well. If you have 2 contexts then none of the states or buffers are in any way connected and any call you make to the openGL will only effect the currently bound context. So detaching the item means deleting it, the only connection that the the `SurfaceTexture` has is the texture ID which is then not usable anywhere else. It might be confusing but think of it this way: If you deleted the connection between your CPU object (surface texture) and the GPU data (the texture) then the texture should be deleted or the texture data becomes garbage and you have a memory leak.

It is hard to understand why you even want to detach the texture from the context but if you need to move it from the context for some reason you will need another context which is the actual owner of the texture. For this you will need a shared context which means creating a new context with the main one as an argument in constructor. This way your main context should be able to access the textures owned by a shared context and the other way around. This will also allow you to use multiple threads since the "current context" is per thread.

Comment: I have added more code sample to explain the use case please check. This is not multiple thread.

Comment: Could you not simply create a new surface texture and inject it as current while preserving the old one till you need it? Or if possible sett the new texture id to the surface texture. Detaching from the context is not what you are looking for in your case. You need at least 2 texture in a certain point and they both do need to be attached.

Comment: No, there is no other way to pass the SurfaceTexture to MediaCodec other than MediaCodec videoDecoder.configure(..., surface, null, 0);

Comment: Yes, but the Surface seems to wrap the SurfaceTexture which wraps the texture. So changing at least one of them should be possible. Such as creating another SurfaceTexture with the same texture id.

Answer (score 0):

"The OpenGL ES texture object will be deleted as a result of this call."

Note that for external surfaces deleting the texture object is not the same as the deleting the physical memory; the physical external memory buffers are not owned by the GL, and will still be allocated and available for reuse (you'll just need to recreate a GL texture object to wrap it again if you reimport in to GL).

Comment: I have added code sample to explain my question more. My point is the texture created inside my GL, why the call delete it.

Comment: Because the memory backing the texture object vanishes when you detach the surfaceView.